# how to change the MUI Drawer component appear side

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my first time I use MUI. I want the drawer side to appear on the right, but looks like `anchor='right'` is not executed. What should I do?

```
<ThemeProvider theme={DrawerTheme}>
  <Drawer hideBackdrop anchor='right' className='opacity-1 w-1/12 bg-red-400' open={true}></Drawer>
</ThemeProvider>
```

Comment: Maybe your className makes conflict with the drawer style. Try to remove it and test again

Comment: ok,i will try it ,thank you propose